# Using an enum's default value as a dictionary key without explicitly casting to String

Tags: swift, dictionary, enums, key

If I declare an `enum` like this:

```
enum Keys {
    case key_one
    case key_two
}
```

I can print it and it will be automatically converted to a `String`:

```
print(Keys.key_one) // prints "key_one"
```

If I then make a dictionary that maps `Strings` to whatever (but let's choose `Strings` again for simplicity), I think that it should be able to add a key by using `Keys.key_one` as the key, right? Wrong.

```
var myDict = [String : String]()

/// error: cannot subscript a value of type '[String : String]' with an index
/// of type 'Keys'
myDict[Keys.key_one] = "firstKey"
```

I can do it if I explicitly convert `Keys.key_one` to a `String` like this though:

```
myDict[String(Keys.key_one)] = "firstKey"
print(myDict) // ["key_one": "firstKey"]
```

So I want to do this without having to wrap my `enum` with `String()` every time.

I've tried a few things by doing an `extension` off of `Dictionary` using the `where` keyword with the `Key` and trying to implement new `subscript` functions, but I can't get it to work. What's the trick?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Update and improvement for Swift 4.2

```
extension Dictionary {
    subscript(key: APIKeys) -> Value? {
        get {
            guard let key = key.stringValue as? Key else { return nil }
            return self[key]
        }
        set(value) {
            guard let key = key.stringValue as? Key else { return }
            guard let value = value else { self.removeValue(forKey: key); return }
            self.updateValue(value, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}

protocol APIKeys {}
extension APIKeys {
    var stringValue: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }
}

enum Keys: APIKeys {
    case key_one
    case key_two
}

var myStringDict = [AnyHashable : Any]()
var model1StringDict = [String : Any]()
var model2StringDict = [String : String]()

myStringDict.updateValue("firstValue", forKey: Keys.key_one.stringValue)                    // [key_one: firstValue]
myStringDict[Keys.key_two] = "secondValue"                                                  // [key_two: secondValue, key_one: firstValue]
myStringDict[Keys.key_one] = nil                                                            // [key_two: secondValue]
myStringDict.removeValue(forKey: Keys.key_two.stringValue)                                  // []

model1StringDict.updateValue("firstValue", forKey: Model1Keys.model_1_key_one.stringValue)  // [model_1_key_one: firstValue]
model1StringDict[Model1Keys.model_1_key_two] = "secondValue"                                // [model_1_key_two: secondValue, model_1_key_one: firstValue]
model1StringDict[Model1Keys.model_1_key_one] = nil                                          // [model_1_key_two: secondValue]

model2StringDict.updateValue("firstValue", forKey: Model2Keys.model_2_key_one.stringValue)  // [model_2_key_one: firstValue]
model2StringDict[Model2Keys.model_2_key_two] = "secondValue"                                // [model_2_key_two: secondValue, model_2_key_one: firstValue]
model2StringDict[Model2Keys.model_2_key_one] = nil                                          // [model_2_key_two: secondValue]
```

I specifically changed the types of the 3 dictionaries to show the common ways of typing a dictionary (`[AnyHashable : Any]`, `[String : Any]`, and `[String : String]`), and showed that this works with each of the types.

It's important to note that if you use `updateValue` instead of the assignment operator when the key of your dictionary is `AnyHashable`, then you need to specify the `String` value of the key with `.stringValue`. Otherwise, the exact type of the key being stored will not explicitly be a `String`, and it'll get messed up later if you try to, say, remove a value under your key via assigning `nil` to that key. For a dictionary where the key is specifically typed to be `String`, then the `updateValue` function will have a compile time error saying that the key needs to be a `String`, so you can't mess it up that way.

## Swift 2.3

I figured out the extension solution that I wanted.

```
extension Dictionary {
    
    subscript(key: Keys) -> Value? {
        get {
            return self[String(key) as! Key]
        }
        set(value) {
            guard
                let value = value else {
                    self.removeValueForKey(String(key) as! Key)
                    return
            }

            self.updateValue(value, forKey: String(key) as! Key)
        }
    }

}

enum Keys {
    case key_one
    case key_two
}

var myStringDict = [String : String]()
/// Adding the first key value through the String() way on purpose
myStringDict.updateValue("firstValue", forKey: String(Keys.key_one))
// myStringDict: ["key_one": "firstValue"]
// myStringDict[Keys.key_one]!: firstValue

myStringDict[Keys.key_two] = "secondValue"
// myStringDict: ["key_one": "firstValue", "key_two": "secondValue"]

myStringDict[Keys.key_one] = nil
// myStringDict: ["key_two": "secondValue"]
```

Notice that the declared dictionary key type is `String`, but I'm able to just use `Keys.key_one` and the subscript in the dictionary extension takes care of the rest.

I can probably put some better guarding around the `as!` conversion to `Key`, but I'm not sure it's needed, as I know that my enum can always be converted to a valid `Key` by the `String()` cast.

## Improvement to answer

Even better, since I'm using this for API Keys, I made a blank protocol called `APIKeys` and each model will implement their own `Keys` enum that conforms to the `APIKeys` protocol. And the dictionary's subscript is updated to take in `APIKeys` as the `Key` value.

```
extension Dictionary {
    
    subscript(key: APIKeys) -> Value? {
        get {
            return self[String(key) as! Key]
        }
        set(value) {
            guard
                let value = value else {
                    self.removeValueForKey(String(key) as! Key)
                    return
            }

            self.updateValue(value, forKey: String(key) as! Key)
        }
    }

}

protocol APIKeys {}

enum Keys: APIKeys {
    case key_one
    case key_two
}

enum Model1Keys: APIKeys {
    case model_1_key_one
    case model_1_key_two
}

enum Model2Keys: APIKeys {
    case model_2_key_one
    case model_2_key_two
}

var myStringDict = [String : String]()
var model1StringDict = [String : String]()
var model2StringDict = [String : String]()

myStringDict.updateValue("firstValue", forKey: String(Keys.key_one))    // myStringDict: ["key_one": "firstValue"]
myStringDict[Keys.key_two] = "secondValue"                              // myStringDict: ["key_one": "firstValue", "key_two": "secondValue"]
myStringDict[Keys.key_one] = nil                                        // myStringDict: ["key_two": "secondValue"]

model1StringDict.updateValue("firstValue", forKey: String(Model1Keys.model_1_key_one))  // model1StringDict: ["model_1_key_one": "firstValue"]
model1StringDict[Model1Keys.model_1_key_two] = "secondValue"                            // model1StringDict: ["model_1_key_one": "firstValue", "model_1_key_two": "secondValue"]
model1StringDict[Model1Keys.model_1_key_one] = nil                                      // model1StringDict: ["model_1_key_two": "secondValue"]

model2StringDict.updateValue("firstValue", forKey: String(Model2Keys.model_2_key_one))  // model2StringDict: ["model_2_key_one": "firstValue"]
model2StringDict[Model2Keys.model_2_key_two] = "secondValue"                            // model2StringDict: ["model_2_key_one": "firstValue", "model_2_key_two": "secondValue"]
model2StringDict[Model2Keys.model_2_key_one] = nil                                      // model2StringDict: ["model_2_key_two": "secondValue"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do:

```
enum Keys: String {
    case key_one
    case key_two
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var myDict = [String : String]()

myDict[Keys.key_one.rawValue] = "firstKey"
```

---

**Update**

If you really want to make it work, you can do as below. But these is some risks by forcing the unwrapping.

```
extension Dictionary where Key: StringLiteralConvertible {
    subscript (key: Keys) -> Value? {
        get {
            return self[key.rawValue as! Key]
        }
        set {
            self[key.rawValue as! Key] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

And then you use it like this:

```
myDict[Keys.key_one] = "firstKey"
myDict[Keys.key_one]
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not gonna do it. I might as well just do `String(Keys.key_one)`. Adding `rawValue` everywhere isn't any better than adding `String()` everywhere.

Comment: @TimFuqua Worst case you can use `static let key_one: String` to replace the `case key_one`. I know some people do this.

Comment: @TimFuqua enums and strings are two different types that can't be coerced, you should expect some boilerplate code to be able to use them interchangeably.

Comment: I'm currently putting a bunch of static let Strings into a struct. But there should be a way to do with by extending a dictionary and putting the boilerplate code into that space.

Comment: Whoop, forget it. Didn't see your own answer.

Comment: :) It's fine. But I'm glad that you also were able to independently think of the exact same solution. It validates my own thinking and supports the solution. And you'll get an upvote for that.

Answer (score 0):

How important is it that your keys are Strings? If it's not important, I suggest doing something like:

```
enum Keys {
    case key_one
    case key_two
}

var myDict = [Keys : String]()

myDict[Keys.key_one] = "firstKey"
print(myDict) // [Keys.key_one: "firstKey"]
```

Comment: It's very important that my keys are strings. Simply because they aren't my dictionaries. It's an existing dictionary. There should be some way of making an extension on Dictionary. That's the solution I'm really looking for.